# Android - How to handle intermediate devices

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am developing one application there I come across problem with intermediate devices say Samsung S8+ dpi 560 that fall between XXX and XX. Because of that I am getting graphical issue. Full screen images are not coming properly.

[image]

All we know that in case of Samsung S8+ if it will take image from XXX it will scale down and if it will take image from XX it will scale up.

**Samsung S8+ all though fall between XXX - XX but its screen size is large than XXX Nexus 6. That's why full screen images are not coming properly.**

How I handle such devices ?

Comment: Try with vector image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific layout folder for it layout-sw560dp and create a specific layout file there which will work for all devices with the given dp.